# Replace a value in dictionary while printing

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary, A sample configuration is as below:

```
{
"user_name": "abc"
"password": "xyz"
}
```

I want to print this dictionary, but while printing i want to mask password field in it. 
Print statement should return something like below:

```
{
"user_name": "abc"
"password": "*****"
}
```

Is there a way to achieve it in python?

Comment: Sure, either a custom class for the dictionary or for the password string. Override `__str__()` to affect how the object prints.

Comment: You might look at [reprlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html)

Comment: Is it essential that `str(mydict)` does that, or is it acceptable that a different function does the printing?

Comment: Why would you store a password in plain-text anyway? Even if you overwrite the representation as soon as you store it in plain text there are ways to access it.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to modify the behavior of the `print` function regarding your dictionary, you should create your own dictionary class, inherited from the default Python `dict` and then define your own `__repr__` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy
d2 = copy.deepcopy(d)
d2['password'] = '***'
print(d2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to print the items in your dictionary, rather than customise the dictionary class like others are suggesting. Something like this ought to do:

```
def get_masked_str(mydict):
    result = "{\n"
    for k, v in mydict.items():
        if k == "password":
             v = "*****"
        result += "    " + repr(k) + ": " + repr(v) + "\n"
    result += "}\n"
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function that doesn't use external modules, that replaces the password field with `*`'s.

```
def secure_str(d):
    x={}
    x.update(d)
    x['password']=len(x["password"])*"*"
    return x
```